# watch folder new file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, batch-processing, performance-testing

I need to create a JMeter script for a batch process. The process will be to check for the file in a inbound folder and then watch for processed folder in the outbound folder.

Is there a way to watch if a file has been processed and is the outbound folder. The file in the outbound folder will have the same name

Comment: you mean while your script execute you need a step that will check if file exists?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSR223 Sampler` (or Pre Processor depends on your needs) which check if file exists, for example in Java language:

```
a = new File("/var/tmp/myFile.txt").exists(); 
log.info("file exists "+  a);
```

Other option is execute all in [Linux script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files) called by [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter's [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) like:

1. Add While Controller to your Test Plan
2. Put the following expression into "Condition" area:

   ```
   ${__groovy(!new File('/path/to/outbound/folder').list().contains('expected_file_name'),)}
   ```
3. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler as a child of the While Controller and configure it to sleep for i.e. `500` ms

JMeter will "sleep" until expected file will appear in the outbound folder, once it will be there - JMeter will proceed to execution of sampler(s) below the While Controller.